# Android: return to main activity problems

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, onresume, activity-lifecycle

In my main activity I have a menu and when a menu option is selected an Intent is created and a new activity is started.  When that activity completes the process should return back to the main activity and all its previous states according to the ActivityLifeCycle.

I notice that when it returns back to the main activity, nothing is accessable and the screen dims.  I can only get back to what I expect when I press the menu softkey.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?  Feedback would be appreciated!
Code sample below:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){          
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}    

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings: 
        return true;            
    case R.id.menu_decks:
        Intent launchDecks = new Intent(this, stackDecks.class);
        startActivity(launchDecks);             
        return true;        
    case R.id.menu_exit:  
        this.onDestroy();
        this.finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you properly implementing onStart, onRestart, and on Resume?

Comment: How do you finish second activity? Can you show code?

Comment: My guess is that the menu is still open for some reason when you return. Hard to say without seeing any code. Maybe you can try to close it before you fire the intent.

Comment: Hey all, I added some code which is used in the main activity maybe this can help..

@Nikita - The second activity is basically just a radioGroup and a button.  The button clicked will set some value to a variable and then it will by calling finish();

Comment: @Pennypacker - I never thought of that, I think that might be on the right track..but not sure how to close it before starting the intent

Comment: @Dan - my overrides of onStart/Restart/Resume just contains the super to the associated method.  I'm not sure if they need to be implemented differently?

Answer (score 2):

The code in the first post is actually correct(I have something very similar). There is a great chance the error is in the menu.xml res file, even though it inflates without any problems. Check it is fully consistent in both places, and has the same items. I finally solved it after hours of experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to be confused with the use of super.

super.m() is used to call a superclass method.

If you inherit the method with no override then
super.m() = this.m()
See your super.onDestroy

It s absoluetly useless to override a method m() just to call super.m()
See your onResume

Sometimes it is usefull to call a super clas method, it allows you to benefit from this code in a subclass. For instance here onCreateMenuOptions is overriden and your subclass can benefit from some imitialisation code for a menu.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: -modified the code previously super.onDestroy()..
-i agree with the comment regarding onResume() I removed one line of code inside it which displayed some text to the Toast widget..